# How to update entire document except ID with mongodb c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-.net-driver

At the moment i'm updating the entire document, but if the ID changes i get error message:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException: 'A write operation resulted in an error.
>     After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: BinData(3, B3FD0EE0FF161845BE96BE40A7DDE84B)'

So i want it to ignore the ID field when updating a document.

Here's what i'm doing now:

```
 public async Task<bool> UpdateMatch(Guid id, Match match)
    {
            ReplaceOneResult actionResult
                = await _context.Match.ReplaceOneAsync(m => m.Id.Equals(id),
                match,
                new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });

            return actionResult.IsAcknowledged && actionResult.ModifiedCount > 0;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you considered first finding the document , then updating the relevant properties on the object  and then replacing it directly after using that same object you got on the initial find except with the new properties?

Answer (score 22):

Add 'BsonIgnoreIfDefault' attribute to the InternalId property.

```
public class Document
{
    [BsonId]       
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public ObjectId InternalId { get; set; }
    // rest of document
}
```

Comment: this is better solution when you don't want to generate id manually as well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem which is happening is that MongoDB will add the _id field to the replacement document if it is not specified in either the filter or replacement documents if ReplaceOneAsync is used. If _id is present in both, the values must be equal. However, if I understand your code properly you are trying to find a document by ID and replace it. There is a collection method called FindOneAndReplace() or FindOneAndReplaceAsync() that I would have used if I were you. You might want to check out the MongoDB documentation for this:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/

Hope this helps you!